# Prevent EditText from gaining focus instead of ImageView after returning from called activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

After returning to calling `Activity`, if `EditText` had focus and keyboard was being displayed before calling the `Activity` then the screen scrolls to that `EditText`.

Follow the below scenario.

1. `Activity` starts. No `EditText` has focus.
2. Select 1st `EditText` to gain focus and let the keyboard popup.
3. Scroll down to `ImageView` while the keyboard is on the display screen and tap it which calls another `Activity`.
4. New `Activity` Opens and returns an `Image`.
5. On returning, the focus is back to the same `EditText` which was having focus only without the keyboard on displayed.

I have to again scroll down to the `ImageView` which is suppose to show the result of the `Image`. How prevent such thing from happening.
I want that on returning to the calling `Activity` the focus should be exactly where it left off instead of being scrolled to the previous `EditText`.

I have created this scenario and verified the issue in the below `XML`. I have given id's to the ones I used for testing.
The `ImageView` with id `"result"` is what goes outside the screen and the `EditText` which I used for testing and which gains focus is with id `"edt_test"`.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/activity_focusable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="onClickGetSignature"
            android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="onClickGetSignature"
            android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="onClickGetSignature"
            android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Also set `android:focusable=true` in your LinearLayout to prevent the `EditText` from gaining focus.

Comment: @zed the issue still persists

Comment: when you came from another activity, call `requestFocus()` on `LinearLayout` or `ImageView`.

Comment: @AsifPatel requestFocus() on LinearLayout worked. Thank you very much.